# Flutter Custom Checkbox

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a checkbox like in the image, but I have no idea how to change the checkbox icon and border. If you could help with this situation, I would greatly appreciate it

My Checkbox Design:

[image]

Comment: What will be the ui on checked and unchecked state?

Comment: When it is unchecked, the orange square in the middle will not be left, only the border will remain.

Comment: Can you include two images?

Comment: without a single image for now :/

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Comment: check `ToggleableStateMixin` mixin - it contains `buildToggleable` which has to be called from `build` method - `buildToggleable` takes a custom painter where all the states of your checkbox are drawn (use `ToggleablePainter` as a painter, which implements logic to draw a radial ink reaction for this control)

Comment: I used the regular checkbox widget and this widget does not provide these parameters. I could only add a border, but it was not like in the image.